# How can I include Controller Advice and Service Method under the same transaction?

Tags: spring-boot

In our Spring Boot application, we are saving data to audit trail object for REST API calls (POST/PATCH) in the in CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter class. In one of the Service classes we have some validations; an exception is thrown when the checks fail. The requirement is to be able to rollback the audit trail data when an exception occurs. Currently we are unable to add the CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter  and Service method under the same transaction scope. Anyone has ideas on how to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: Please provide more detail (e.g. what you've tried, code examples, etc.)

Comment: We tried adding Transactional annotation on the Request Body Adapter as indicated with no luck 
`
@ControllerAdvice
@Transactional("appTransactionManager")
public class CustomRequestBodyAdviceAdapter extends RequestBodyAdviceAdapter {
    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(..) {

 save(auditobj)

}
@Service
@Transactional("appTransactionManager")
public class SampleService extends BaseService {

public void updateStatus() {
 save(obj)
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

We couldn't find an appropriate solution  to handle transaction the way we would have liked. Hence we added functionality to save audit trails data in each of the service methods wherever we needed to capture audit trails.